# I can see the definition in the header file, so why is the compiler complaining of an "undefined reference"?

Tags: c, arm, raspberry-pi

I purchased a development board from Analog Devices for their ad7176-2 analog to digital IC. I downloaded the "generic driver files" (not OS specific).
I've been compiling them on the Raspberry Pi, an arm device running a variant of Debian called Raspian.
I'm using Code::Blocks as an IDE and I've used both the "GNU GCC" and the "GNU ARM GCC" compilers.

I get the error **"undefined reference to 'AD7176_regs'**

here's the code from the AD7176_regs.h file, which is #included in AD7176.h which is #included in AD7176.c which is where the error is found by the compiler.

The code:

```
    /*! AD7176 register info */
typedef struct _st_reg 
{
    int32_t addr;
    int32_t value;
    int32_t size;
}st_reg;

/*! AD7176 registers list*/
enum AD7176_registers
{
    Status_Register = 0x00,
    ADC_Mode_Register,
    Interface_Mode_Register,
    Register_Check,
    Data_Register,
    IOCon_Register,
    ID_st_reg,
    CH_Map_1,
    CH_Map_2,
    CH_Map_3,
    CH_Map_4,
    Setup_Config_1,
    Setup_Config_2,
    Setup_Config_3,
    Setup_Config_4,
    Filter_Config_1,
    Filter_Config_2,
    Filter_Config_3,
    Filter_Config_4,
    Offset_1,
    Offset_2,
    Offset_3,
    Offset_4,
    Gain_1,
    Gain_2,
    Gain_3,
    Gain_4,
    Communications_Register,
    AD7176_REG_NO
};


**Defining the undefined**


#ifdef AD7176_INIT
/*! Array holding the info for the AD7176 registers - address, initial value, size */
st_reg AD7176_regs[] = 
{
    {0x00, 0x00,   1}, //Status_Register
    {0x01, 0x0000, 2}, //ADC_Mode_Register
    {0x02, 0x0100, 2}, //Interface_Mode_Register
    {0x03, 0x0000, 3}, //Register_Check
    {0x04, 0x0000, 3}, //Data_Register
    {0x06, 0x0000, 2}, //IOCon_Register
    {0x07, 0x0000, 2}, //ID_st_reg
    {0x10, 0x8002, 2}, //CH_Map_1
    {0x11, 0x0000, 2}, //CH_Map_2
    {0x12, 0x0000, 2}, //CH_Map_3
    {0x13, 0x0000, 2}, //CH_Map_4
    {0x20, 0x0000, 2}, //Setup_Config_1
    {0x21, 0x0000, 2}, //Setup_Config_2
    {0x22, 0x0000, 2}, //Setup_Config_3
    {0x23, 0x0000, 2}, //Setup_Config_4
    {0x28, 0x020A, 2}, //Filter_Config_1
    {0x29, 0x0200, 2}, //Filter_Config_2
    {0x2a, 0x0200, 2}, //Filter_Config_3
    {0x2b, 0x0200, 2}, //Filter_Config_4
    {0x30, 0, 3}, //Offset_1
    {0x31, 0, 3}, //Offset_2
    {0x32, 0, 3}, //Offset_3
    {0x33, 0, 3}, //Offset_4
    {0x38, 0, 3}, //Gain_1
    {0x39, 0, 3}, //Gain_2
    {0x3a, 0, 3}, //Gain_3
    {0x3b, 0, 3}, //Gain_4
    {0xFF, 0, 1} //Communications_Register
};
#else
extern st_reg AD7176_regs[AD7176_REG_NO];
#endif
```

And here is one of the places where we want to access the register value, but get the error message.

```
        /***************************************************************************//**
* @brief Reads the conversion result from the device.
*
* @param pData - Pointer to store the read data.
*
* @return Returns 0 for success or negative error code.
*******************************************************************************/
int32_t AD7176_ReadData(int32_t* pData)
{
    int32_t ret;

    /* Read the value of the Status Register */
    ret = AD7176_ReadRegister(&AD7176_regs[Data_Register]);

    /* Get the read result */
    *pData = AD7176_regs[Data_Register].value;

    return ret;
}
```

If I get this fixed, should I be using GCC for ARM or just GCC. The code will be running on the Raspberry Pi and controlling the ADC IC on the developement board.

Thanks           Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `AD7176_INIT` is not defined so you end up with:

```
extern st_reg AD7176_regs[AD7176_REG_NO];
```

It declares `AD7176_regs` but does not define it and it's the reason why you get the linker *undefined reference* error.

Now an object definition should not appear in a header file, a definition should be put in the `.c` file.

Comment: yes. I see "#define AD7176_INIT" at the very beginning of AD7176.c   It's curious that it was written that way. I'll try moving the definition to the .c file.

Comment: Is the `define` before the include of the `AD7176_regs.h` file?

Comment: Yes. It's the first line. I left the definition as it was and moved the define to below the include. That fixed that error, which was the only one being reported. But now I've got 11 errors!!     I'll work on  them and post another question if I get stuck again. Thanks for solving that first problem ouah. Should I move the definitions into the .c file?   Peter

Comment: @PeterStewart Actually if the `define` is before the include, it does not make sense that you get the undefined reference error. Put an `#error` directive after the `#ifdef AD7176_INIT` of the `.h` to check which case you really have. Regarding the definitions in the `.c` file, as the files are provided by the vendor I would not modify them to much but you have to be sure the `.h` is not included elsewhere which would make some linker multiple object definition errors.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I moved the define back to before the include. I put the #error directive in and  it showed that AD7176_INIT was not defined.       AD7176_INIT appears in only three places in all the files. In the enum and in the #else in AD7176_regs.h and in the #define in AD7176.c.     It seems it's only purpose is to check if the #definer directive was read in AD7176.c first.     I don't know much about compiling, but I'm going to go and look it up now.